# Arduino pick a random word from given array

Tags: c++, arrays, random, arduino

I have this code that prints a word on an LCD:

```
void setup(){
lcd.print("Hello World");
}
```

I want it to pick a random word from this array:

```
const char *words[] = {"Happy","Sad","Angry","Worried","Shy","Excited","Suprised","Silly","Jealous","Hurt","Cold","Hot","Energized","Bored","Sick","Love","Upset"};
```

So basically using this array I want it to pick a random word from this array and then to display it on the LCD using the lcd.print method. Any ideas? Sorry if the answer is very obvious, I am only beginner at Arduino.

Comment: **lcd.print(words[ random(16) ]);** Good luck, it seems to be a homework....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the length of the array, then use [`random`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/) to get a number up to that bound:

```c
const int len = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);
lcd.print(words[random(len)]);
```